# Change attr with an effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a way of changing the source of my image using `attr` which will also provide a fade effect along the way. I have tried one of the other answers I found here, but it's not giving the the desired effect.

**This is how it currently looks like:** http://jsfiddle.net/zeaVx/

You can notice how the whole thing totally fades out before taking the other image in. That's not what I need. I need the change to be instant, just like CSS's `:hover` but only with the fading effect.

How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: There is no way to animate between attributes. You need to append a new image and fade it in.

Comment: The solution doesn't have to be in jQuery as long as it gives me the effect I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 2 separate `</img>` tags, wrap them in a container, put one on top of the other, then simply fade in/out the top image.

### HTML

```
<div class="button-container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/q4A2GtV.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jztqeIv.png" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.button-container {
    position: relative;
}
.button-container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('.button-container').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('img:last-child').stop().fadeOut();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('img:last-child').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zeaVx/1/**

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution! However, there is a slight issue here: I have several buttons which need to get hover effect and I added it to each of them. But now, each button is above one another and I don't know how to fix it since I'm not a good CSS styler. P.S: They all have to be in one row (inline)

Comment: Dugi, JSFiddle demo please. As a guess: consider changing the container `</div>` in to an inline element e.g. `</span>`

Answer (score 0):

use this **jsfiddle.net/Curt/PLwam/1/**    it might be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var active = false;

            $(function() {
                $('#fb_icon')
                        .mouseover(function() {
                    if (!active) {
                        active = true;
                        $(this).hide();
                        $(this).attr('src', 'dummyImg2.jpg').fadeIn('slow');
                        active = false;
                    }
                })
                        .mouseout(function() {
                    if (!active) {
                        active = true;
                        $(this).hide();
                        $(this).attr('src', 'dummyImg1.jpg').fadeIn('slow');
                        active = false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="dummyImg1.jpg" id="fb_icon" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```